# Can gradient tape in tensorflow differentiate nested functions of the same network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, backpropagation

That is to say if I have a differentiable model g, and a differentiable function f (which could also include models).

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
  for_ in range(n):
     r = g(r)
  loss = f(r)
grad = tape.gradient(loss, g.trainable_variables)
```

would tape.gradient apply backpropagation through time for n steps on g?

Answer (score 2):

You can use matplotlib to create two graphs and see how they compare. The red line is for the target and the blue line is for the prediction result.

```
tf.GradientTape(
persistent=False, watch_accessed_variables=True
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O5Wg.jpg)

Comment: Please, try not to post code as images :)

Comment: so will my code execute bptt?